# Counting Number Of Specific Record In Database

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a application which needs to aware of latest number of some records from a table from database, the solution should be applicable without changing the database code or add triggers or functions to it ,so I need a database vendor independent solution.
My program written in java but database could be (SQLite,MySQL,PostgreSQL or MSSQL),for now I'm doing Like that:
In a separate thread that is set as a daemon my application sends a simple command through JDBC to database to be aware of latest number of the records with condition:

```
while(true){
          SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mytable WHERE exited='1'
}
```

and this sort of coding causes DATABASE To lock,slows down the whole system and generates huge DB Logs which finally brings down the whole thing!
how can i do it in a right way to always have latest number of certain records or only counting when the number changed?

Comment: I don't see why a statement like that would cause huge DB Logs, but you may be able to improve the system by creating an index on `exited`

Comment: Querying the database in a busy loop is a terrible idea. Could you change your code so that you only query the count on-demand? Where are you using the count in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement should not -- by itself -- have the behavior that you are describing.  For instance, nothing is logged with a `SELECT`. Now, it is possible that concurrent `insert`/`update`/`delete` statements are going on, and that these cause problems because the `SELECT` locks the table.

Two general things you can do:

1. Be sure that the comparison is of the same type. So, if `exited` is a number, do not use single quotes (mixing of types can confuse some databases).
2. Create an index on `(exited)`. In basically all databases, this is a single command: `create index idx_mytable_exited on mytable(exited)`.

If locking and concurrent transactions are an issue, then you will need to do more database specific things, to avoid that problem.

Comment: Also, if the background thread is not auto-commit, keeps the connection open, and never commits, the open transaction may cause issues. Call `conn.commit()` after running the `SELECT` to close the transaction. Calling `commit()` when no updates have executed may seem counter-intuitive, but it's needed.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff
the thread do the select statement all the time without stop,you say that this approach is safe?!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, make sure that exited is indexed.

Also, you can set the transaction isolation on your query to do a "dirty read"; this indicates to the database server that you do not need to wait for other processes' transactions to commit, and instead you wish to read the current value of exited on rows that are being updated by those other processes.

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED is the standard syntax for using "dirty read".